# How to set my xlabel at the end of xaxis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want my x axis has the label like this format

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 Xlabel
```

but I try code below it result me in 2 lines

```
self.axes.set_xticks(np.arange(0,6,1))
self.axes.set_xlabel('Xlabel', fontsize=9,x=1,y=1)
```

=> my result :(

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 
        Xlabel
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to align axis label to the right or top in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38186072/how-to-align-axis-label-to-the-right-or-top-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Would be nice if someone had a good answer for 3d plots.  `set_label_coords` does not seem to change anything.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

When setting the xlabel, the `x` parameter assigns the position in axis units, so 0 is the origin and 1 is the right edge of the plot. `y` is ignored as it's expected to be a default value, just below the tick marks.

To override this behavior, you can set the position in axis units using the `Axis` `set_label_coords` [method](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_label_coords). You can use other units by also providing a transform.

Here is an example of this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,6,1))
label = ax.set_xlabel('Xlabel', fontsize = 9)
ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(1.05, -0.025)

plt.savefig('labelAtEnd.png')
plt.show()
```

Resulting in:
[image]

The x value (1.05) was chosen to position the label outside the Axes frame. The y value (-0.025) was chose as a best guess to the position you desired. Using a transform, it might be possible to automatically position the text in line with the `Tick` labels.

**EDIT:**

Here's an extended example using a transform. It is not necissarily more helpful to use the last ticklabel's transform, because it does not take into account the size of the text and how it is aligned. So to get a somewhat desired effect, I had to 1) use the same font size for my x label, 2) position the vertical alignment (va) to 'top', and 3) position the horizontal alignment to 'left'. The transform for each tick is set for data units for x (because it's an xaxis) and axis units for y (0 to 1), but displaced by a fixed padding (in pixels) from the x axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,6,1))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,6,1))
label = ax.set_xlabel('xlabel', ha='left', va = 'top', )#fontsize = 9)

# need to draw the figure first to position the tick labels
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.draw(fig.canvas.get_renderer())

# get a tick and will position things next to the last one
ticklab = ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[0]
trans = ticklab.get_transform()
ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(5.1, 0, transform=trans)

plt.savefig('labelAtEnd2.png')
plt.show()
```

This results in:

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to give an example of using a transform as well?

Comment: @Zhenya I added an example, but it turns out not to be trivial.

Answer (score 23):

In addition to what @Yann already said, it's actually easier to do this with `annotate`. It will also stay in the correct position when zoomed/panned.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

ticklabelpad = mpl.rcParams['xtick.major.pad']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim([0, 5])

# Add the label as annotation. The "5" is the padding betweent the right side
# of the axis and the label...
ax.annotate('XLabel', xy=(1,0), xytext=(5, -ticklabelpad), ha='left', va='top',
            xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here is my variant of using @JoeKington method.
I change last tick label to axis name. First I set last ticks to empty strings and then use annotate(). I've used annotate() because I need to control font size of axis label.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.xlim(50, 70)
plt.ylim(100, 250)

ax = plt.gca()
# clears last tick label
xticks = ax.get_xticks().tolist()
xticks[-1] = ''
ax.set_xticklabels(xticks)
yticks = ax.get_yticks().tolist()
yticks[-1] = ''
ax.set_yticklabels(yticks)
# sets axes labels on both ends
ax.annotate('$t$', xy=(0.98, 0), ha='left', va='top', xycoords='axes fraction', fontsize=20)
ax.annotate('$x$', xy=(0, 1), xytext=(-15,2), ha='left', va='top', xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points', fontsize=20)

plt.show(block=True)
```

Maybe someone knows more elegant way to do this, because it is ridiculously complex operation.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I use the solution provided by @JoeKington, with the extension of having label font properties imposed on the text produced by `ax.annotate(...)`.

This is important when axis labels are formatted differently than other text.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

ticklabelpad = mpl.rcParams['xtick.major.pad']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim([0, 5])

dx_in_points = 5
fontproperties = ax.xaxis.get_label().get_fontproperties()

ax.annotate('XLabel', xy=(1,0), xytext=(dx_in_points, -ticklabelpad), ha='left', va='top',
         xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points', fontproperties=fontproperties)

plt.show()
```