# How to align axis label to the right or top in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

By default `matplotlib` plots the axis label at the center of the axis. I would like to move the label in such way that it is aligned with the end of the axis, both for the horizontal and vertical axis. For example for the horizontal axis I would like to see:

```
+--------------------+
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
+--------------------+
                 label
```

Is it possibile to do it with the global setting of matplotlib?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of [v3.3](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/users/whats_new.html#align-labels-to-axes-edges) you can now set these with the `loc` argument of `set_xlabel` and `set_ylabel`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Left plot
options = ['left', 'center', 'right']
fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(options), 1, constrained_layout=True)

for ax, loc in zip(axs, options):
    ax.plot([1, 2, 3])
    ax.set_xlabel(f'xlabel loc={loc!r}', loc=loc)
```

```py
# Right plot
options = ['bottom', 'center', 'top']
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, len(options), constrained_layout=True)

for ax, loc in zip(axs, options):
    ax.plot([1, 2, 3])
    ax.set_ylabel(f'ylabel loc={loc!r}', loc=loc)
```

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |

Comment: Optical illusion when scrolling on this @_@

Answer (score 35):

**UPDATE**

Current 2023's Matplotlib has a new keyword `loc=…` for `plt.[xy]label`.
From `xlabel` doc string

> `loc : {'left', 'center', 'right'},`
>     `The label position. This is a high-level alternative for passing`
>     `parameters *x* and *horizontalalignment*.`

and you can write simply

```
plt.xlabel('x_description', loc='right')
plt.ylabel('y_description', loc='top')
```

[image]

---

My other answer is still a good one, because the idea of getting an object, modifying it and setting it back is a good idea on its own, but here it is an alternative, cleaner solution:

```
...
plt.xlabel('x_description', horizontalalignment='right', x=1.0)
plt.ylabel('y_description', horizontalalignment='right', y=1.0)
...
```

as you can see, no more magic numbers, and works both for `xlabel` and `ylabel`.

Note that in both cases we are going to change the horizontal alignment, for reasons that were eventually clear to me when I first changed the vertical alignment in `ylabel`...

Comment: Can't edit becauce of 6 character limit, there should be `plt.xlabel('x description', horizontalalignment='right', x=1.0)`

Comment: @anatol  exchange `horizontalalignment` and `x`/`y` (in both statements please) — that's more than 6 characters... and thank you for catching my mistake!

Comment: If I change it to `horizontalalignment = 'left'` it breaks. Can you explain how this is working (i.e. how the `x` and `y` parameters factor in)?

Comment: @Greenstick I'm afraid I cannot help, because almost 5 years later I don't remember the details of the problem any more. Further, _"it breaks"_ is not excessively helpful…

Answer (score 8):

An ad hoc solution, that introduces the magic value `25` that I don't understand very much, to say the least, is

```
plt.xlabel('pollo', horizontalalignment='right', position=(1,25))
```

A more sensible approach is to use whichever `y` position the `axes.xaxis` has choosen... With this idea in mind a sane procedure is usually like

1. get the object using a `.get_object(...)` method of the parent container
2. modify the object
3. update the parent using its `.set_object(...)` method

In our case, we make the plot, then we get the current axis `ax` that contains the `xaxis` that contains the `label` whose position and alignment we want to modify.

```
...
plt.xlabel('...')
...
ax = plt.gca()
label = ax.xaxis.get_label()
x_lab_pos, y_lab_pos = label.get_position()
label.set_position([1.0, y_lab_pos])
label.set_horizontalalignment('right')
ax.xaxis.set_label(label)
...
plt.show()
```

With respect of acting directly on `matplotlib`'s defaults, I've browsed the `plt.rcParams` data structure but I haven't spotted anything useful.  Of course that doesn't mean that it is impossible, just that I cannot see a viable solution.

Comment: I am wondering if it is possibile to do it via global settings of matplotlib

Comment: @RuggeroTurra At some point between 2016 and 2023 Matplotlib introduced  the `loc` keyword for axes labelling, eg `loc='right'` for placing the *x* label to the right. Most relevant re your remark, the location is controlled by a rc parameter, `[xy]axis.labellocation`. Meglio tardi