# X-Y Axis labels placement

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x, y = [-1, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 1]
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (12, 7))
ax.scatter(X, Y, s = 200, color = "red")
ax.axis([-2, 3.01, -2.01, 2])
ax.spines["left"].set_position("zero") # alternative position is "center"
ax.spines["right"].set_color("none")
ax.spines["bottom"].set_position("zero")
ax.spines["top"].set_color("none")
ax.set_xlabel("x-axis")
ax.set_ylabel("y-axis")
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

[![Fig][1]][1]

The X-Y axis labels are inside the figure. How to set the axis labels properly: outside the boundaries of the figure.

Here is the correct answer : [How to set my xlabel at the end of xaxis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290938/how-to-set-my-xlabel-at-the-end-of-xaxis)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jixy3.png

Comment: The correct answer is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290938/how-to-set-my-xlabel-at-the-end-of-xaxis. ax.xaxis.set_label_coords, ax.yaxis.set_label_coords are the relevant options.